# Generate Custom Class (ImageView Descendant) As Content for Notification (RemoteViews)

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-notifications, remoteview

I have a custom View that is extending ImageView (called PieView) and since this is one of the allowed views to be included in RemoteViews, this should theoretically work.

I am sending a Notification to the device's notification bar using `NotificationCompat.Builder` with a custom View, which includes a blank ImageView, which I want to replace with my custom class (which is a descendant of ImageView).

Here's what I use to build the Notification:

```
    final PieView pie = new PieView(c);

    // My own method that redraws the View using this.invalidate()
    pie.setRam(totalRam, freeRam);

    pie.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    pie.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    pie.layout(0, 0, pie.getMeasuredWidth(), pie.getMeasuredHeight());
    pie.buildDrawingCache(true);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pie.getDrawingCache());

    pie.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ivPie, bitmap);

    mBuilder.setContent(remoteViews);
```

However, this results in `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the following line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pie.getDrawingCache());
```

I am assuming the View is not drawn yet since it's not placed anywhere in the layout. How to work around this issue? I am familiar that only a portion of Views are supported to be included in the Notification's body, but there must surely be a way to pre-create my custom View as a static image and add it to the (allowed) ImageView using RemoteViews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a custom View that is extending ImageView (called PieView) and since this is one of the allowed views to be included in RemoteViews, this should theoretically work.

Since there is no `PieView` in Android, it cannot be "one of the allowed views to be included in `RemoteViews`", and it will not work, in theory or in practice. While `ImageView` is allowed, subclasses are not.

> How to work around this issue?

Draw your pie to a `Bitmap`, perhaps via a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`, and apply the `Bitmap` using `setImageViewBitmap()` on `RemoteViews`. However, bear in mind that the overall `RemoteViews` structure needs to be reasonably small (under 1MB), so do not make your bitmap too big.

Comment: I've tried that, but everytime I try to built a `Bitmap` using `Bitmap.createBitmap(pie.getWidth(), pie.getHeight().....)` out of my `PieView` the getWidth and getHeight methods always return 0, so `createBitmap` fails (I am guessing the PieView is not ready/rendered). So the real question is, how to force the PieView to be rendered programmatically, get its Bitman and use it as a value for `setImageViewBitmap`?

Comment: @WordPressDeveloper: Get rid of `PieView` and draw the pie to a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas` of your desired size (http://madandroid.blogspot.com/2011/05/drawing-on-widget-canvas.html). Or, you can try creating a standalone `PieView` (i.e., not a child of anything) and call `measure()` and `layout()` on it yourself, and see if that works.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, although I am not sure if it will work, because I don't know if we'll know how large the Notification will be, and in turn - how big we should create the Canvas/Bitmap to draw on. I'll ponder over it and try to implement it and post back. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @WordPressDeveloper: "because I don't know if we'll know how large the Notification will be" -- you definitely will not know how large the `Notification` will be, as details of the drawer can vary by device manufacturer.

Comment: So you are suggesting I draw a fixed-size canvas (e.g. 150dp x 150dp) and position it inside the ImageView using XML (e.g. stretch/skew/centerFit/gravity/etc)?

Comment: @WordPressDeveloper: Personally, I just wouldn't put a pie chart in a `Notification`. :-) That being said, it's possible that what you are describing will work -- I have never tried that.